# Calculate frequency of triples in a C array for indexing

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I have an array of integers (possibly thousands), like

```
int p[] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 5, 1, 7, ...
```

from which I want to generate a set of indices for each unique triple; for the list above, something like:

```
0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 4, ...
```

I've coded up a simple C++ implementation (though a plain C or Obj-C implementation would do just as well or better), but am sure there's room for improvement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24*3; i++) {
    std::ostringstream sstr;
    sstr << p[3*i] << "," << p[3*i + 1] << "," << p[3*i + 2];
    freq[sstr.str()] += 1;
}

for (auto i = freq.begin(); i != freq.end(); i++) {
    std::cout << i->first << " => " << i->second << std::endl;
}
```

This just counts the frequencies of each triple, but could be trivially adapted to assign the desired indices. My question is, how can this be made more time/space efficient (bearing in mind that the runtime target is a mobile device)? Specifically,

1) What might be a better data structure than `std::map` for this purpose? I'd like to avoid introducing new dependencies (e.g. boost, unless it's header-only)
2) Is there a better key to use than a `string`? I thought about using a number for space efficiency, such as 5^a * 3^b * 2^c, but was concerned about exceeding numerical limits
3) Is there a better algorithm/approach than the one outlined here?

Comment: Make sure you properly check your bounds. `i < 24*3` is a code smell. You should do something like `const size_t p_size = sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p); for (size_t i = 0; i < p_size - 3; ++i ) { ... }`. Also, rather than doing `3*i`, `3*i + 1`, etc., I'd suggest using a step-size of 3 and then doing `p[i]`, `p[i + 1]`, rather than multiplying like you are now. It will typically be more efficient and more intuitive at maintenance time.

Comment: Good points, though the hardcoded 24*3 is just an artifact of the quick-and-dirty example above. It won't look like that in the final code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed with Armen that it's generally OK. I would probably make a map with triples as keys and a set of indices as values:

```
typedef std::set<size_t> index_set;
typedef std::tuple<int,int,int> triple;
typedef std::map<triple, index_set> frequency_map;
```

And then:

```
const auto t = std::make_tuple(p[i], p[i+1], p[i+2]);
freqs[t].insert(i);
```

Then every `i` in `freqs[t]` is such that `(p[i], p[i+1], p[i+2])` equals `t`.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity looks OK to me. using `std::map` looks OK to me. As for the key, it seems to me that a `struct` with 3 `int`s is more appropriate than a `string`. But I don't think it matters that much

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely change the key to a simple 3 int struct; a tuple may also be a nice idea. This should cause a substantial performance improvement, because it would remove any potential heap allocation from strings and the overhead associated with the string stream.

Also, since you have thousands elements and no order constraints, an `unordered_map` may be a better container choice.